# Read android expansion files cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, expansion

I need to know if there is a possibility to read expansion files from cordova 6.0.0  , I could not find a way to make it from the html . Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Did you manage to work out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the xapkreader plugin: 
https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/tree/cordova-6.5.0

it lets you access your expansion file content using an easy url:

```
<img src="content://com.test.expansion/myfile.png">
```

Make sure to follow the installation instructions tediously because it requires more work than any other plugin I have installed.

Hint: you can find your API Key on the "Services & APIs" tab in the Developer Console